# I am not able to check/uncheck the checkbox(flutter)

Tags: flutter, checkbox

This is the minimum code
I am not able to check/uncheck the checkbox. What to do??

```
         Row(
           children:<Widget>[
           Text("English"),
           Checkbox(
            checkColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            value:false,
            onChanged: (bool value) {
              setState(() {
                if(value==true) {
                  lang.languages = "English";
                  print(value);
                }
              });
            },
          )])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bool checkboxState = false;

         Row(
           children:<Widget>[
           Text("English"),
           Checkbox(
            checkColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            value:checkboxState,
            onChanged: (bool value) {
              setState(() {
                checkboxState = !checkboxState;
                if(value==true) {
                  lang.languages = "English";
                  print(value);
                }
              });
            },
          )])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't interact with the checkbox mostly because of the static boolean that you passed to the `value` property

```dart
value:false,
```

You need to do as such:

````dart
         bool checkboxState = false;

         Row(
           children:<Widget>[
           Text("English"),
           Checkbox(
            checkColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            value:checkboxState,
            onChanged: (bool value) {
              setState(() {
                checkboxState = !checkboxState;
                if(value==true) {
                  lang.languages = "English";
                  print(value);
                }
              });
            },
          )])
    ```
````

Answer (score 1):

```
   Checkbox(
    checkColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
    value:false,  // <-- If you put a value (true/false) here, it'll never change
```

Instead you need to create a variable...

```
bool myVariable = false // Somewhere far up in your class, before your build function begins),
```

Then you use that....

```
   Checkbox(
    checkColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
    value: myVariable
```

And toggle it when you click the checkbox:

```
     onChanged: (bool value) {  // <-- notice that the value is the new state of the checkbox.
       setState(() {
          myVariable = value;
       });
     },
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you don't change the value of `value:false` :)

Try implementing it like this :

```
class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  bool checkboxState = false;

  void _setEnglish(bool newValue) => setState(() {
    checkboxState = newValue;

    if (checkboxState) {
      lang.languages = "English";
    }
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Checkbox(
      value: checkboxState,
      onChanged: _setEnglish
    );
  }
}
```